# How can I make ipad Safari bookmark list wider?

Tags: ios, ipad, safari, accessibility, bookmarks

How can I make ipad Safari bookmark list wider ?

I want to see as much text as possible for each bookmark, not have more than half the screen devoted to a dimmed-out web page.

iPad Air 2, iOS 9.3.1

See picture.  [image: Example Picture of problem]

When you choose larger text sizes, the default value doesn't allow for much text to show.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to make it wider without a jailbreak.  The only thing you can do is to make the text smaller so you can see more of it.  That stinks but it's the only thing available.